# Pandas Filtering Between Grouped Rows

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I had a pandas table "df" that looks like this

| FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00147 | 65,69 | 1 | 2 | 65,67 |
| 00147 | 65,68 | 2 | 3 | 65,69 |
| 00147 | 66,70 | 3 | 4 | 66,68 |
| 00147 | 65,69 | 4 | 5 | 66,70 |

I want to filter the rows if a FIELD5 value does appears in the FIELD2 column and if they share they share the same FIELD1 value.

Desired output

| FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00147 | 65,69 | 1 | 2 | 65,67 |
| 00147 | 66,70 | 3 | 4 | 66,68 |

I tried filtering using a duplicate database "df_1"

```
df[(df['FIELD1']==df_1['FIELD1']) & (df['FIELD5'].isin(df_1['FIELD2'])]
```

However, more rows were filtered based on rows which don't share that FIELD1 value. Any advice?

Comment: Your results don't seem to match up with what you are asking for.  I don't see `65,67` anywhere in `'FIELD2'` let alone in the rows you've shown to pass the filter.  Do you mean that it can be ***any*** value in the comma-separated list?  If so, then why don't all rows pass the filter?  You need to explain this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join/merge to achieve this:

```
df_merge = df.merge(df
                   , left_on=['FIELD1','FIELD2']
                   , right_on=['FIELD1','FIELD5']
                   ,suffixes=('_l', '_r')
                   )

df_merge.loc[:,['FIELD1_l','FIELD2_l','FIELD3_l','FIELD4_l','FIELD5_l']]
```